# Connecting lines to nearest point using QGIS

Tags: qgis

[image]I am trying to connect lines to the **nearest points**. I want to extend the line or create another one with the same properties.

Most of the time, the line is in a buffer of 50cm near the point but I can't find a solution. I only see "connect two points with a line"...

Can you help me ?

Comment: I added it @BERA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Menu <kbd>Processing</kbd> > <kbd>Toolbox</kbd> > <kbd>[Shortest line between features](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#shortest-line-between-features)</kbd>:

> Creates a line layer as the shortest line between the source and the
> destination layer.

---

This connects to points to one point on the line. If you only want to connect to start-/end-points of the lines (dangling ends), first run [`Geometry by expression`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisgeometrybyexpression) with `union(start_point($geometry), end_point($geometry))` to create the dangling ends, then use the output of this as Destination layer.

*Initial lines (black) and points (red) as well as dangling ends (green), connected to the lines layer (blue dotted line) and to the dangling ends (red line):*

[image]

Comment: It works like a charm ! Thank you

Comment: Ok ! I'll read this article :)